# How can I add HTML5 validation to ensure a password is at least 5 characters long?

Tags: css, html

I have just started to learn about HTML5 validation.

Can someone tell me how I can validate that an `<input>` field is longer than 5 characters?

Comment: “At least 5” and “longer than 5” are different things. The title of a question should match its content.

Comment: minlength works .. for html5 pattern and required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to ask how to ensure that an input field has at least 5 characters?

```
<form>
    <input type="password" required pattern=".{5,}" name="pwd1"></p>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

change input type if you are not trying this on password type fields

Answer (score 3):

You could use the pattern attribute

```
<input type="password" … pattern=".{6}"> /* Six characters minimum */
```

Check out the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML5_form_additions#Validation) for more information.